# SQLite: Write-Ahead Logging (WAL journal mode) with attached database

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, wal

Working on database optimization, we split our database into two databases: db and db2. A low priority background thread is inserting into db2. Some of the queries on db are joined with db2, so we need to attach db2 to db. We enable WAL because want it all to be multithreaded.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, ...);
db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
db.execSQL("attach " + db2path + " as db2");
```

To understand the problem, we run a simple two thread test. The first thread is inserting rows into db, and the second thread is selecting from db. Each thread prints the time delta from the previous loop and the time we were inside the database.

```
thread 1 loop:                             | thread 2 loop:
    t1 = getTime()                         |   t1 = getTime()
    db2.execSQL("insert into ....");       |   db2.execSQL("select ....");
    t2 = t3                                |   t2 = t3
    t3 = getTime()                         |   t3 = getTime()
    log("i: "+(t3-t1)+", delta: "+(t2-t1)) |   log("s: "+(t3-t1)+", delta: "+(t2-t1))
```

What we see is that the selecting thread is blocking the inserting thread. This can be emphasized by doing a huge (and slow) select, and a tiny insert. You will see that the insert time and the delta increase approximately to the time of the select. If we don't run the slow threads, the insert thread speeds up considerably.

Digging into the source code of SQLiteDatabase I found the following lines in `SQLiteDatabase#enableWriteAheadLogging()`:

```
// make sure this database has NO attached databases because sqlite's write-ahead-logging
// doesn't work for databases with attached databases
if (mHasAttachedDbsLocked) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "this database: " + mConfigurationLocked.label
                + " has attached databases. can't  enable WAL.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now to my questions:

1. What is the meaning of the comment? What exactly doesn't work? Is it some old code left behind? The documentation of ATTACH DATABASE (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) explicitly indicates that ATTACH + WAL is OK (with a small caveat.)
2. Why is the Android binding code trying to protect us from SQLite internal issues? The way I see it, it's supposed to be a thin interface layer.

*Edit*: I reported this as a bug in [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220987). Will update if an answer appears there.

Answer (score 0):

WAL allows readers and a writer at the same time, but only from different connections. You should never use the same connection (the `SQLiteDatabase` object) from multiple threads.

The WAL setting is permanent; you do not need to execute it every time after opening the database.

1. The meaning of the comment is exactly what it says. (Nobody guarantees that this comment is correct.)
2. Sometimes, the Android framework tries to be clever. But you can just execute `PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL` manually.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I'm talking about the SQLiteDatabase object's source code.

Comment: And nobody but its author could answer the questions as written.